# creating new object from other

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

only first way of creating object in javascript is letting me create new object from it. second and third way of creating object are throwing error
can someone tell me why this is happening. and let me know what mistake i am making in code.

```
'use strict'

// First Way for creating object
var log = function(){
    this.name = 'nitesh',
    this.lastName =  'Yadav',
    this.age =  '21'
}
Object.defineProperty(log,'name',{
    enumerable: false,
    writable: false,
    configurable: false
})
var for = new log(); ***// Works fine*** 
console.log(foo.name); // nitesh

// Second Way for creating object

var log2 = {
    name: 'nitesh',
    lastname: 'yadav',
    age: '21'
}
var foo2 = new log2; ***//Not working***
console.log(foo2.name) // Result error Why???

// third Way for creating object

var log3 = Object.create(Object.prototype,{
    name:{
        value: 'nitesh',
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    },
    age: {
        value: '21',
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
})

var foo3 = new log3; ***//Not working***
console.log(foo3.name) // Result error Why???
```

Comment: var for = new log(); will throw exception because `for` it is reserved word and you can't use it as variable name

Comment: `Object.create` - create new object, not a class. You can't call `new log3` because it is not a class (and not a constructor)

Comment: Naming should all be redone. Start with that!

Comment: var foo2 = new log2; ***//Not working because log2 is an object instance NOT a constructor function for it.***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first case is creating "class" and than you can make as many objects as you want.

In second and third case you are creating Objects itself and you simply cannot create object from object. You can use them right after creating:

```
// Second Way for creating object

var log2 = {
    name: 'nitesh',
    lastname: 'yadav',
    age: '21'
}
// var foo2 = new log2; // This line is not needed 
console.log(log2.name) // No Error

// third Way for creating object

var log3 = Object.create(Object.prototype,{
    name:{
        value: 'nitesh',
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    },
    age: {
        value: '21',
        enumerable: true,
        writable: true,
        configurable: true
    }
})

//var foo3 = new log3; // This line is not needed 
console.log(foo3.log3) // No Error
```